# How do I handle Models and the await() function in Play 1.2.x?

Tags: playframework

My problem is that the following (pseudo)code:

```
Model aModel = Model.findById(1);
await(something);
aModel.causeALazyLoad();
```

Causes an exception on the last line of "no session or session was closed". This is because, as best as I can tell, that calling an await() suspends the request and closes the hibernate session.

What's the proper way, or best practice, to handle this? Much of the time I'll want to start a job, load some entities, then await the result of the job. Now those entities are all from an old session so are difficult to use properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the action referring to the http session or the hibernate session? 

If the former, sounds like a known bug.

See

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1180-session-id-changes-with-suspended-requests

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099463/session-context-lost-in-play-async-await

Comment: I meant the hibernate session. And from what I'v learned since posting this question what I wanted to do wasn't possible in Play 1.x, the hibernate session and JDBC model doesn't support suspended connections.

Answer (score 0):

there might be another thread that is executing 'something' (e.g. Callable) in statement:

```
await(something);
```

If this is the case, you can try to propagate current JPA instance to this thread, like this:

```
final JPA jpa = JPA.local.get();
await(new Job() {
    public void doJob() throws Exception {
        JPA.local.set(jpa);
        //do something
    };
}.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late to help :), but the solution I found was to merge the originally loaded model into the new Hibernate session after the await()

```
Model aModel = Model.findById(1);
await(something);
aModel = aModel.merge();
aModel.causeALazyLoad();
```